# Was bedeutet "in die Knie zwingen"?

Tags: meaning, translation, meaning-in-context

Was bedeutet: "Das Problem zwingt mich in die Knie"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es bedeutet, dass Du aufgeben musst. Es ist zu groß/zu schwer für Dich.

Mit einer Last auf den Schultern hat das Bild nichts zu tun, sondern mit einer Kampfhandlung, bei der der Sieger eine Unterwerfungsgeste abverlangt.

Answer (score 1):

Das ist ein Sprachbild. Stelle Dir einfach vor, dass Du etwas sehr Schweres auf Deinen Schultern trägst. Das Ding ist so schwer, dass Du nicht mehr aufrecht stehen kannst. Du musst die Knie beugen, vielleicht musst Du Dich sogar hinknien.

Dieses Bild wird auf die Schwere eines Problems übertragen. Das Problem ist so schwer, es ist so schwerwiegend, dass Du es nicht mehr tragen kannst. Das Problem zwingt Dich in die Knie.

Answer (score 0):

Es kommt von den Ringern und ist rund 3000 Jahre alt. Steht auch im Ilias von Homer. Wer mit dem Knie den Sand beim Ringekampf berührte, gab einen "Gang" ab. Er war der Unterlegene. Wer drei Gänge abgab, hatte verloren. Wer seinen Gegener dreimal in die Knie zwang, war der Sieger. Unwichtige Anmerkung: Wer auf beiden Schulterblättern lag, hatte sofort verloren.